# Using styles/classes in template literal angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to style a search input field in which the alias of a sublocation appears on the left and parent.name appears on the far right for each sublocation in a drop-down fashion.

I have followed some related articles of people using document.getElementById() and appending style to it. But the reason why this wouldn't work for me is that i'm using html input with a custom directive to show the list of sublocations to choose from.

This is what i'm trying to do.

```
temp.push({
 ...
alias: `<div>
         <p style="float:left">${eachSubLoc.alias}</p> 
         <p style="float:right">${this.titleCase.transform(eachSubLoc.parent.name)}</p> 
       </div>`,
});
```

I tried using HTML in a template literal which is working as shown but i cannot add styles to the

tag like 'float: left' etc..
Is there something additional that needs to be done in the app to access styling in a template literal?

The version i'm using is Angular 4.

Any leads would be appreciated. Thankyou.

Comment: Are you using Material Design or any other similar UI library?

Comment: Yes im using Angular Material 2.0.0-beta.8. I cannot upgrade this though because it causes problems with the prod build